# How to write comments in the YAML programmatically in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, comments, yaml

I usually put comments in the YAML so that the reader could understand YAML parameters quickly.

```
%CommentC: "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Filtering Setting~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
WindowSize: 3
Sigma: 3
LowerThreshold: 25
HigherThreshold: 35
```

But how can I write the comment programmatically in OpenCV using `FileStorage`?

Comment: How do you write the YAML files now? Manually (using e.g. `std::ostream` and the output operator `<<`)? Using some library?

Comment: I use cv::FileStorage with << operator but I am not sure it works with comments.

Comment: So you are doing something like `someFileStorage << "WindowSize: " << theWindowSize << '\n'`? Then just write the comments the same way: `someFileStorage << "%CommentC: \"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Filtering Setting~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\"\n";`

Comment: It returns an error. That's why I'm asking the question. There may be some official way to write YAML comment.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the error (complete and unedited), together with the code that causes the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function:

```
/* writes a comment */
CVAPI(void) cvWriteComment( CvFileStorage* fs, const char* comment, int eol_comment );
```

This is working example:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

        cvWriteComment(*fs, "a double value", 0);
        fs << "dbl" << 2.0;

        cvWriteComment(*fs, "a\nvery\nimportant\nstring", 0);
        fs << "str" << "Multiline comments work, too!";
    }

    {
        double d;
        string s;
        FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);
        fs["dbl"] >> d;
        fs["str"] >> s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `test.yml` file:

```
%YAML:1.0
# a double value
dbl: 2.
# a
# very
# important
# string
str: "Multiline comments work, too!"
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Have a nice day!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that! :)

Comment: Is this functionality still present in `OpenCV-3.0`?

Answer (score 2):

The way we use `FileStorage` to write comment in the new version of OpenCV (3.2 or higher) is a bit different from the previous version. This is the function:

```
void cv::FileStorage::writeComment(const String &   comment, bool  append = false)
```

An example:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);

        fs.writeComment("a double value", 0);
        fs << "dbl" << 2.0;

        fs.writeComment("a\nvery\nimportant\nstring", 0);
        fs << "str" << "Multiline comments work, too!";
    }

    {
        double d;
        string s;
        FileStorage fs("test.yml", FileStorage::READ);
        fs["dbl"] >> d;
        fs["str"] >> s;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result (test.yml):

```
%YAML:1.0
---
# a double value
dbl: 2.
# a
# very
# important
# string
str: "Multiline comments work, too!"
```